# TSQL WITH - second reference fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

SQL Server 2008 R2 - Query from 2014 SSMS but fails from code as well.

Strange - first reference to table B works, second fails with an 'Invalid object B' error. What am I doing wrong? GO's don't help.

```
        WITH B as (SELECT BatchOutId, SettleMerchantCode, BatchDate, BatchStatusCode, BatchTransCnt, BatchTotAmt, BatchAdjustAmt, BatchAdjustCnt
        FROM     MAF01
        GROUP BY BatchOutId, SettleMerchantCode, BatchDate, BatchStatusCode, BatchTransCnt, BatchTotAmt, BatchAdjustAmt, BatchAdjustCnt)
        SELECT * FROM B ORDER BY BatchOutId DESC
        SELECT * FROM B ORDER BY BatchOutId DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cte is only valid for one query, not an entire batch.   So once you do the first SELECT * FROM B, that query is finished.   The next query no longer has access to the cte that the first query used.

Comment: Thanks - I had used two SELECTs before but with a UNION between them.

Answer (score 2):

This is as expected.

CTEs are only in scope for the next statement. They are just named queries.

You would need to either

1. Repeat the definition of the CTE.
2. Move the definition out into a view or inline function.
3. Materialise the results into a temp table.

Depending on what you were expecting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has to be duplicate

You can have multiple CTE but only one statement
The two Select are two statements

If you use a #temp then you can have more than one statement